# jQuery loading .each for objects in JSON array

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to write an `.each` statement for objects in a JSON array.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function (key, value){
            ...do stuff...
        }
});
```

Problem is, it's only returning one result because it's only doing an `.each` for `data` when I need it to do an `.each` for the objects inside `data`.  I'm sure it's as simple as `.each(data.something ...)` but I can't figure out what it is.

**EDIT**
Per comment request, data looks like:

```
[["data1","data2","data3"],
 ["data1","data2","data3"],
 ["data1","data2","data3"]
]
```

**EDIT2**

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfgky/) of my working code.  if I change teh `.each` function to just do an `alert` it works, but when I try to build divs, it only spits out one entry.

Comment: what does the data object look like? Can you debug or do an alert(JSON.stringify(data)); ?

Comment: So you want it to loop through: `data1a,data2a,data3a,data1b,data2b...`?

Comment: I want to loop through `[ [stuff], [stuff], [stuff] ]` if that makes sense.

Comment: It does not. As far as I can tell, you're already doing that.

Comment: I know, right?!  It's driving me nuts.

Comment: Per your JSFiddle in Edit2 -- you are updating the $("#test").html()...this would completely overwrite the content for each iteration of the loop.  Do you want to change that to .append()?

Comment: @Jason, THANK YOU!!! OMG, I feel like a moron.

Comment: Your welcome.  Glad it was simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally suggested using $.map() to create an array.

But the actual problem was that the OP was overwriting the html in each iteration of the loop.  Editing my response to show the actual answer.

Answer: OP needed to change .html() to .append() in his .each() loop.

Comment: A user-defined function.  The map function takes an array and a function as its parameters.

Comment: So should I have a `function fn()` somewhere?  I'm confused.

Comment: Answer was in the comments, but you gave it.  Maybe alter response?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a nested loop:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function (idx1, value1){
            $.each(value1, function (idx2, value2){
                //...do stuff...
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Tried this, didn't work.  It's not the data that's not displaying, it's the iteration of the `.each`.

Comment: I'm sorry, that makes no sense to me. Please clarify what you want to loop through in what order.

Comment: So, the JOSN array starts with `[`, then the first object is declared inside that array with another `[` -- This is the one I want `.each` to iterate.  After the second dimension, comes the actual data which is `"data1","data2","data3"`, those are the values that need to be printed.  so, for each 2nd level object, print its objects/values.

Comment: That sounds like what I originally had. I'm sorry, I don't think I can be much more help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfgky/) isn't the `.each` loop -- it's that you're using `.html()` to add code, which will replace everything inside the specified element with your new code.

Use `.append()` instead of `.html()` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is not a JSON object, just do the following

```
$.each($.parseJSON(data), function (key, value){
  ... stuff...
}
```

depending on the object, you should do a [Map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
// Therefore, convert it to a real array
var realArray = $.makeArray( data )

// Now it can be used reliably with $.map()
$.map( realArray, function(val, i) {
  // do something 
});
```

**Edit - Test on fiddle**

With your object we can check that it is a nested array, so you have to double loop on it:

```
var data = [["data1","data2","data3"],
 ["data1","data2","data3"],
 ["data1","data2","data3"]
];

$.each(data, function(key, item) {
    $.each(item, function(i, val) {
        alert(val);
    })
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GQJqE/)

**Edit 2 - Code for you situation!**

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, item) {
            $.each(item, function(i, val) {
                alert(val);
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Why is that not JSON?  I was encoded as JSON from PHP, AJAX call is set to `dataType: 'json',` Wouldn't AJAX run the `error:` if it wasn't JSON?

Comment: The problem is it iterates through each `data1` or `data2` item.  I want it to parse the parent level of those items.  `[["data1","data2"], //<---for each of these ["data1","data2"]//<--and this one too ]`, so the `.each function would run two times.

Answer (score 0):

Use one more loop

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    $.each(value, function(i, val) {
        console.log(val)
    })
})​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/huNFQ/)**

Comment: What is the code that you are using to build the div's ... Can you update that code as well